# Setup Contentful Javascript SDK in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, contentful, contentful-vault

I'm trying to implement Contentful Javascript SDK on a React Native project (without Expo).

This is the code:

```
const {createClient} = require('contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js')

useEffect(() => {
    getContentfulData()
}, [])

const getContentfulData = async () => {
    var client = createClient({
    adapter: (config) => {
        config.adapter = null
        return fetch(config)
    },
    space: '---',
    accessToken: '---',
    })

    await client
        .getEntries()
        .then((entries) => {
            console.log(entries)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

But I'm getting **TypeError: Network request failed** over and over again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
const { createClient } = require('contentful/dist/contentful.browser.min.js')

  const client = createClient({
    space: '*********',
    accessToken: '****************************************',
  })

    client
      .getEntries({
        content_type: 'trendingBlogs',
      })
      .then(entry => console.log(entry))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

your missing the getEntries parameters.
i.e

```
{
  content_type: 'trendingBlogs',
}
```